# Better way to get scroll Parameters?

Tags: javascript, math, scroll

So, I'm trying to get some parallax scrolls in my document. So I did:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollPost()};

function scrollPost () {
    var i = window.scrollY;
    blockShift(i);
    console.log(i);
}

function blockShift (i){
    var blockOne = document.querySelector(".block-1");
    var blockTwo = document.querySelector(".block-2");
    var y = i - 900

    if (i < 980){
    blockOne.style.transform = `translateY(${y/3}px)`
    blockTwo.style.transform = `translateY(${y/-3}px)`
    } 
}
```

However, I wonder if there's a more accurate way to get numbers? One of the problem is that scrollY number is variable depending on screen size. I've also tried.

```
var x = window.screen.width;
var i = window.scrollY;
var number = Math.round(i/x);
```

Which gives me a 0.xxxxxxx number. How would I get something better?

**Edit**: this also works well

```
var x = window.screen.width;
var i = window.scrollY;
var a = i / x;
var numb = Math.round(a * 10) / 10;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"get something better"_, what exactly constitutes _"better"_? `scrollY` is a subpixel precise value, I don't believe any other property has a finer granularity.

Comment: Better constitutes something that is the same across different screen sizes, something that doesn't skip when scrolling fast (Though that's because of the onscroll), something that's easily worked with, for CSS styles. Like opacity, or VH.